# xts time series error with PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, xts, performanceanalytics

Hi I have a dataframe object called NormalizedPnL.  Here it is:

```
  print(head(NormalizedPnL))
  print(class(NormalizedPnL))
  print(class(NormalizedPnL[,1]))
  print(class(NormalizedPnL[,2]))
  print(class(NormalizedPnL[,3]))

  businessdate    start A            Strat B           Strat C
1   2014-01-01  0.000000000        0.00000000       0.000000000
2   2014-01-02  0.016764200        0.04218263       0.011912007
3   2014-01-03  0.001179697       -0.02683310      -0.000897083
4   2014-01-06 -0.033131903        0.01902207       0.021104512
5   2014-01-07 -0.033215587       -0.06347915      -0.018900792
6   2014-01-08  0.045181350       -0.00732205      -0.016600410
[1] "data.frame"
[1] "Date"   # you can see here the this column is a date
[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
```

Now I make it a xts object:

```
  NormalizedPnL_xts<- xts(NormalizedPnL[,-1], order.by= as.Date(NormalizedPnL[,1]))
  print(head(NormalizedPnL_xts))
  print(class(head(NormalizedPnL_xts)))
  print(class(NormalizedPnL_xts[,1]))
  print(class(NormalizedPnL_xts[,2]))
  print(class(NormalizedPnL_xts[,3]))

               Strat A            Start B         Strat C 
2014-01-01  0.000000000        0.00000000       0.000000000
2014-01-02  0.016764200        0.04218263       0.011912007
2014-01-03  0.001179697       -0.02683310      -0.000897083
2014-01-06 -0.033131903        0.01902207       0.021104512
2014-01-07 -0.033215587       -0.06347915      -0.018900792
2014-01-08  0.045181350       -0.00732205      -0.016600410
[1] "xts" "zoo"
[1] "xts" "zoo"
[1] "xts" "zoo"
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

you can see that all the columns are zoo

Now I try to use performance Analytics:

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(NormalizedPnL_xts,geometric= FALSE,cex.axis=1.5)
```

And I get the error:

```
The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass
 in        names     from a data object with one column, you should use the 
 form 'data[rows, columns,     drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as 

'1985-03-15'. 
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, 2, value = c(90600, 60400, 302000 : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 1
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, 8, value = c(-742200, -494800, -2474000 : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 1
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?  The error mentions having 1 column but I have 3.

Comment: Works fine for me. Must be a syntax error on your part. It looks like you set `NormalizedPnL_xts <- NormalizedPnL` at some point.

Comment: Can you explain? I am not sure what you mean. Is this line: NormalizedPnL_xts<- xts(NormalizedPnL[,-1], order.by= as.Date(NormalizedPnL[,1])) incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

NormalizedPnL <-
structure(list(businessdate = c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03", 
"2014-01-06", "2014-01-07", "2014-01-08"), StratA = c(0, 0.0167642, 
0.001179697, -0.033131903, -0.033215587, 0.04518135), StratB = c(0, 
0.04218263, -0.0268331, 0.01902207, -0.06347915, -0.00732205), 
    StratC = c(0, 0.011912007, -0.000897083, 0.021104512, -0.018900792, 
    -0.01660041)), .Names = c("businessdate", "StratA", "StratB", 
"StratC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"))

NormalizedPnL_xts <- xts(NormalizedPnL[,-1], order.by=as.Date(NormalizedPnL[,1]))
charts.PerformanceSummary(NormalizedPnL_xts,geometric=FALSE,cex.axis=1.5)
```

Comment: hmmm This is so weird that my code does not work. It appears to do the exact same thing.  I'm lost

Comment: You probably have a typo or syntax error somewhere. Try it in a new R session.

Comment: No luck.Do you think it is something with my rownames. when I do  rownames(NormalizedPnL)  i get 1,2,4....  but when I do  rownames(NormalizedPnL_xts) I get NULL.  I am not sure how to interpret this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008212/drawdowns-performance-analytics-error-factor-and-numeric  but it has to do with rownames.

Comment: That answer works because they're passing a data.frame to the function. You can do that, but the rownames _must_ be the values to be used for the xts index, and they must be in a suitable format. xts objects shouldn't have non-NULL rownames, so that's not a problem. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. It works for me with the latest PerformanceAnalytics on CRAN.